# Using a nested NSMutableDictionary

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, nested, nsmutabledictionary

simple question, I need to structure data in the following format:

```
UserID:
    1 {
        Name = Bob
        Surname = Hope
    }
    2 {
        ...
```

I can used an NSMutableDictionary to add a single layer with keys, but I am unable to create a child associate with a certain key.

I have tried creating a mutable dictionary and assigning that to a key:

```
NSMutableDictionary *dic = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

NSArray *keys = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"Name", @"Surname", nil];

NSArray *details = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"Bob",@"Hope", nil];

NSDictionary *person = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithObjects:details forKeys:keys];

[dic setValue:@"1" forKey:@"id"];

[[dic objectForKey:@"id"] setDictionary: person];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is better to use an array of dictionaries, each dictionary representing a user.

```
NSMutableArray *users= [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

NSArray *keys = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"Name", @"Surname", nil];

NSArray *details = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"Bob",@"Hope", nil];

NSDictionary *person = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithObjects:details forKeys:keys];

[users addObject:person];
```

Answer (score 0):

u can also set the objects for dictionary in this way

```
    [dic setObject:person forKey:@"id"];
```